# Responsive CSS, How to make clock maintain position with image on resize

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design, css-position

The image I'm working with is located at this URL: http://migentemobile.com/wp-content/themes/migente/img/migente-mobile-carousel.png [image: phone]

As you can see the clock on the image is static. I've been asked to put a working js clock overtop of the static clock for eye candy.

I have the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jKUvZ/20/).

Or here's the full markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Migente Carousel with working clock</title>
    <!-- IE Fix for HTML5 Tags -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
        html, html a {
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
        }
        .container {
            background-color:#fff;
            margin:auto;
            width:70%;
        }
        #clock {
            -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
            -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
            background-color:#000;
            color:#9C9C9C;
            display: table-cell;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
            font-family:"Helvetica Narrow", "Arial Narrow", Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            height:20px;
            left:833px;
            padding:1px;
            position:relative;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
            top:-157px;
            width:50px;
            zoom: 1;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function checklength(i) {
            if (i < 10) {
                i = "0" + i;
            }
            return i;
        }

        function clock() {
            var now = new Date();
            var hours = checklength(now.getHours());
            var minutes = checklength(now.getMinutes());
            var seconds = checklength(now.getSeconds());
            var format = 1; //0=24 hour format, 1=12 hour format  
            var time;

            if (format == 1) {
                if (hours >= 12) {
                    if (hours == 12) {
                        hours = 12;
                    } else {
                        hours = hours - 12;
                    }
                    time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
                } else if (hours < 12) {
                    if (hours == 0) {
                        hours = 12;
                    }
                    time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
                }
            }
            if (format == 0) {
                time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
            }
            document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = time;
            setTimeout("clock();", 500);
        }
        window.onload = clock;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://migentemobile.com/wp-content/themes/migente/img/migente-mobile-carousel.png" class="carousel-macbook" alt="carousel" />
        <div id="clock"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

With my current resolution, this works fine. However upon browser resize or resolution change, the clock is no longer positioned properly. I'd like to make the image responsive as well as maintain the js clock's position to the image if the browser gets resized or is viewed on different platform i.e. mobile, tablet, desktop, etc...

I was reading http://learnlayout.com/position.html (Slide 7 / 19) about position relative, which I thought would be the objective since I want the clock's position to be relative based on the image's size. However I'm obviously missing something here because when I resize the browser or view on mobile the clock does not stay where it belongs.

Any help with this project would be greatly appreciated!

*UPDATE*

**Looks OK in**

- Safari 5
- IE 10 & 9
- Chrome 26 & 25

**Position of clock is off in**

- Firefox 19

**Position OK but text is not rotating in**

- Opera 12
- IE 8 & 7 & 6

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working fine for me on Chromium v25, even when I resize the window. It doesn't remain correct on Firefox v20 though.

Comment: Thanks for the info Xotic750. Still some css bugs (including responsiveness) to work out I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS transform property is not supported prior to IE9.

For Firefox (and maybe also Opera), the "display: table-cell" attribute is causing the browser to refuse to render the "position: relative" attribute. Try "display: inline-block" instead.

"position: relative" positions the element relative to it's **parent** container. So it is positioning the element according to ".container", NOT img. When I look at .container in jsFiddle (by giving it a "background: #ff0099"), it looks like it will be both a different size and in a different position for devices, especially when the devices rotate. That's probably what is messing up your clock's position relative to the image, which has no position relative to the changing .container.

If you make ".container" the exact dimensions of the image, and give the image a position inside of it (i.e., "position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"), you should be able to manipulate the clock's position much more consistently for devices, because the image and the container will be positioned identically, which they now are not.

BTW I think the clock is very cool!

Comment: Wow! Your solution worked brilliantly! Thank you so much both for the great answer and for making "position: relative" a lot more clearer. I just started using "display: table-cell" and am still learning the pros and cons of it, so thanks for the inline-block suggestion too, worked great! :)